# Convert PDF to images in php

Tags: php, image, pdf

These are the steps I am trying to achieve:

1) Upload a PDF document on the server.

2) Convert the PDF document to a set of images, and saving them.

Any ideas for doing #2 using php??

Comment: http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=134543

Comment: http://usefulangle.com/post/24/pdf-to-jpeg-png-with-pdfjs this will help

Answer (score 2):

If you have the ImageMagick extension compiled into PHP, it should be able to read in PDFs and convert them to any common image format.  I don't believe the GD extension (which is more common) has PDF capabilities, sadly.